# Scrapy spider not including all requested pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a Scrapy script for Yelp that is, for the most part, working. Essentially I can supply it with a list of Yelp pages and it should return all reviews from all pages. The script so far is below:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
import re

from yelp2.items import YelpReviewItem

RESTAURANTS = ['sixteen-chicago']

def createRestaurantPageLinks(self, response):
    reviewsPerPage = 40
    sel = Selector(response)
    totalReviews = int(sel.xpath('//div[@class="rating-info clearfix"]//span[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/text()').extract()[0].strip().split(' ')[0])
    pages = [Request(url=response.url + '?start=' + str(reviewsPerPage*(n+1)), callback=self.parse) for n in range(totalReviews/reviewsPerPage)]
    return pages

class Yelp2aSpider(Spider):
    name = "yelp2a"
    allowed_domains = ["yelp.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.yelp.com/biz/%s' % s for s in RESTAURANTS]

    def parse(self, response):
        requests = []

        sel = Selector(response)
        reviews = sel.xpath('//div[@class="review review-with-no-actions"]')
        items = []

        for review in reviews:
            item = YelpReviewItem()
                item['venueName'] = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
                item['reviewer'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-name"]/a/text()').extract()
                item['reviewerLoc'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-location"]/b/text()').extract()
                item['rating'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract()
                item['reviewDate'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content').extract()
                item['reviewText'] = review.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()
                item['url'] = response.url
                items.append(item)
        return items

        if response.url.find('?start=') == -1:
            requests += createRestaurantPageLinks(self, response)
            return requests
```

However, the problem I'm running into is that this particular script scrapes every page of every requested review EXCEPT for the first page. If I comment out the last "if" statement, it only scrapes the FIRST page. I suspect all I need is a simple "else" command but I am stumped... help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** This is the code as it currently stands based on assistance received...

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
import re

from yelp2.items import YelpReviewItem

RESTAURANTS = ['sixteen-chicago']

def createRestaurantPageLinks(self, response):
    reviewsPerPage = 40
    sel = Selector(response)
    totalReviews = int(sel.xpath('//div[@class="rating-info clearfix"]//span[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/text()').extract()[0].strip().split(' ')[0])
    pages = [Request(url=response.url + '?start=' + str(reviewsPerPage*(n+1)), callback=self.parse) for n in range(totalReviews/reviewsPerPage)]
    return pages

class Yelp2aSpider(Spider):
    name = "yelp2a"
    allowed_domains = ["yelp.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.yelp.com/biz/%s' % s for s in RESTAURANTS]

    def parse(self, response):
        requests = []

        sel = Selector(response)
        reviews = sel.xpath('//div[@class="review review-with-no-actions"]')
        items = []

        for review in reviews:
            item = YelpReviewItem()
            item['venueName'] = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewer'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-name"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['reviewerLoc'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-location"]/b/text()').extract()
            item['rating'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewDate'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewText'] = review.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = response.url
        yield item

        if response.url.find('?start=') == -1:
            requests += createRestaurantPageLinks(self, response)
            for request in requests:
                    yield request
```

As mentioned in a comment below, running this code as-is crawls every desired page, but it only returns one review per page rather than all of them.

I tried Changing `yield item` to `yield items`, but an error message of `ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list' in <GET http://www.yelp.com/biz/[...]>` is returned for every URL crawled.

Comment: So what was the problem with this after all?

Comment: I think you also want to replace `sel.xpath(//` for the value of `item['venueName']` with `review.xpath(.//`, right?

Comment: I edited my answer with a correction. This way it works for me, let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Did it work in the end...?

Comment: Yes! Finally! Thanks for all of your help! I'm going to post the solution that worked momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer did indeed lie in the indentation of one single `yield` line. This is the code that ended up doing what I needed it to do.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
import re

from yelp2.items import YelpReviewItem

RESTAURANTS = ['sixteen-chicago']

def createRestaurantPageLinks(self, response):
    reviewsPerPage = 40
    sel = Selector(response)
    totalReviews = int(sel.xpath('//div[@class="rating-info clearfix"]//span[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/text()').extract()[0].strip().split(' ')[0])
    pages = [Request(url=response.url + '?start=' + str(reviewsPerPage*(n+1)), callback=self.parse) for n in range(totalReviews/reviewsPerPage)]
    return pages

class YelpXSpider(Spider):
    name = "yelpx"
    allowed_domains = ["yelp.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.yelp.com/biz/%s' % s for s in RESTAURANTS]

    def parse(self, response):
        requests = []

        sel = Selector(response)
        reviews = sel.xpath('//div[@class="review review-with-no-actions"]')
        items = []

        for review in reviews:
            item = YelpReviewItem()
            item['venueName'] = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewer'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-name"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['reviewerLoc'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-location"]/b/text()').extract()
            item['rating'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewDate'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewText'] = review.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = response.url
            yield item

        if response.url.find('?start=') == -1:
            requests += createRestaurantPageLinks(self, response)
            for request in requests:
                    yield request
```

Thanks to everyone for helping out a noob!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorganize the methods a bit. First parse restaurant page in `parse()` method. Then, return requests for reviews and handle responses in another method, e.g. `parse_review()`:

```
import re

from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

from yelp2.items import YelpReviewItem


RESTAURANTS = ['sixteen-chicago']

class Yelp2aSpider(Spider):
    name = "yelp2a"
    allowed_domains = ["yelp.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.yelp.com/biz/%s' % s for s in RESTAURANTS]

    def parse(self, response):
        reviewsPerPage = 40
        sel = Selector(response)
        totalReviews = int(sel.xpath('//div[@class="rating-info clearfix"]//span[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/text()').extract()[0].strip().split(' ')[0])
        pages = [Request(url=response.url + '?start=' + str(reviewsPerPage*(n+1)), callback=self.parse_review) for n in range(totalReviews/reviewsPerPage)]
        return pages

    def parse_review(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        reviews = sel.xpath('//div[@class="review review-with-no-actions"]')
        for review in reviews:
            item = YelpReviewItem()
            item['venueName'] = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewer'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-name"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['reviewerLoc'] = review.xpath('.//li[@class="user-location"]/b/text()').extract()
            item['rating'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewDate'] = review.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content').extract()
            item['reviewText'] = review.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = response.url
            yield item
```

Comment: No dice. This still only returns every page except for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning items/requests in more than one place, you should replace your `return` statements with `yield` statements, which turn your function into a generator, which returns a new element each time it's generated (yields it), without exiting the function until they are all returned. Otherwise, as your code is now, your function will exit after the first `return` and won't get to sending the requests for the following pages.

Edit: Correction - you should yield one item/request at a time, so:

Replace

```
for review in reviews:
    item = ...
return items
```

with

```
for review in reviews:
    item = ...
    yield item
```

and replace

```
return requests
```

with

```
for request in requests:
    yield request
```

Comment: I tried swapping the `return` statements with `yield` statements as you suggested, both using my original code and the code suggested above, but in both cases I get error messages. Specifically I tried changing `return items` to `yield items` but this gives me an error of `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`. Indeed, I've tried pretty much every variation I can think of in terms of swapping `return` for `yield` and all of the permutations either give me an error message or don't change the behavior.

Comment: The error you mention should show up if you used both `yield` and `return` in the same function, if you change one `return` in a function to `yield`, you should change them all. This is just my 2 cents regarding `yield`, I'm not sure about other errors or your original problem.

Comment: I've updated the code above based on your suggestions--it's now crawling every page but it's only returning one item per page. See updated code above.

Comment: `yield item` should be inside the loop not outside - see my example. Indent that row one more time (so that it yields each item, not just the last one)